# Wireless Power Transfer Circuit Theory

Tags: circuit-analysis, oscillator, theory

I made [this](http://voltage.g6.cz/bezdratovy-prenos-energie.php) circuit, and it is working fine. But didn't understood the theory in it. How is it putting a frequency in the coil? It did not match with any of the oscillator circuits. And also it is not working in LTSpice.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic LC oscillator where the two haves of the coil are coupled inductors. Here is a simplified version...

[image]

There is a good explanation of LC oscillators like this one here...

http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/oscillators.html

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVGqRY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is both L1 and L2 with C3 forming the tank circuit here? Where L1 is also the feedback inductor? And what is the C1 C2 and R1 here is it forming some filter circuit?